# Can a same PersistentVolume 'pv' bind to many PersistentVolumeClaims 'pvc' in different namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

My kubernetes is on-premises not cloud provider.
I can bind once, but when I create a second pvc it is pending.

```
k get pvc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                        STATUS        VOLUME                                  CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
my-prod   my-nfs                            Pending                                                                                        1d
my-test   my-nfs                            Bound         my-nfs                                  20Gi     RWX                           23d
```

Comment: It seems to be 'no'.